# How do I select a range from query?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, query

I am trying to find a way to query my two tables in my database. So the first table contains WiFi hotspots and the other table contains city zones. So the.geom and geom are geometry columns and I am trying to see if the WiFi geometry is within the zone geometry, also I am trying to select some range within the zones. Here is my query,

```
 SELECT  distinct a.geom
FROM wifi a, zones b where ST_Within(a.thegeom, b.geom) and 
b.zone BETWEEN '101' AND '108'
OR b.zone BETWEEN '301' AND '303'
OR b.zone = '306'
OR b.zone = '402';
```

After this query is done, instead of returning the geometry within the zones range, all geometries are outputted. I'm a bit annoyed and frustrated with this.

Comment: Are both geometries in the same coordinate system?

Comment: Yes, yes they are..

Comment: Is zone a text field? or numeric?

Comment: zone is a integer field.

Comment: Try getting rid of the quotes.  So, b.zone BETWEEEN 101 AND 108, etc

Comment: I did, now the query yields nothing. Returns blank.

Comment: Have you tried adding parentheses to your query for the part that selects the zones?  Like (b.zone BETWEEN..... ..... or b.zone = '402')

Comment: I just tried it and that didn't work.

Comment: Numbers must be without quotes `BETWEEN 101 AND 108` http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp.

Comment: You can't meaningfully use BETWEEN on text ranges, `SELECT * FROM ( SELECT x::text FROM generate_series(1,100) AS t(x) ) AS f WHERE f.x BETWEEN '1' AND '13';` Other than that, if it already `int` he has precedence wrong. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `BETWEEN` only works on numeric types (not strictly true but I don't want to confuse you), so you'll have to set your zones to integer (or smallint, etc) to use it in the fashion you desire in your example.

```
ALTER TABLE zones ALTER COLUMN zone TYPE int;
```

Second, precedence is highly important in your query. In the above you've got

```
SELECT  distinct a.geom
FROM wifi a, zones b
WHERE ST_Within(a.thegeom, b.geom)
  AND b.zone BETWEEN 101 AND 108
    OR b.zone BETWEEN 301 AND 303
    OR b.zone = 306
    OR b.zone = 402;
```

However, that's **not** getting parsed as you want. This is how it is getting parsed

```
SELECT  distinct a.geom
FROM wifi a, zones b
WHERE (
  ST_Within(a.thegeom, b.geom)
  AND b.zone BETWEEN 101 AND 108
)
  OR b.zone BETWEEN 301 AND 303
  OR b.zone = 306
  OR b.zone = 402;
```

what you probably want is this.

```
SELECT  distinct a.geom
FROM wifi a, zones b
WHERE ST_Within(a.thegeom, b.geom)
  AND (
    b.zone BETWEEN 101 AND 108
    OR b.zone BETWEEN 301 AND 303
    OR b.zone = 306
    OR b.zone = 402
  )
```

`BETWEEN AND` has the highest precedence. Than `SQL-AND`. Then `SQL-OR`.

Comment: +1. This is what I was trying to say in my comments, but you described it much better.